# How to make the first element aligned to the right and the other elements in the left of that first?

Tags: html, css

I have two HTML elements: label and span inside a div 
 I want the label aligned to the right and the span in the left of the labe;

like this :
[image]

But this is what I have:

[image]

this is the HTML and  CSS code:

```css
.barcode-pdf-body div {
  text-align: right;
  border-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.barcode-pdf-body div label {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "myFont";
}
.barcode-pdf-body div span {
  font-family: "myFont";
}
```

```html
    <div>
        <label>
            {% trans 'constraint_number' %}:
    
        </label>

        <span>
            {{ correspondence.number }}
        </span>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try it like this:

```
div label {
float:right;
} 
div span {
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can change only CSS file, check code below:

```css
.barcode-pdf-body div {
  text-align: right;
  border-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;

  display: flex;
}

.barcode-pdf-body div label {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "myFont";

  order: 2;
}

.barcode-pdf-body div span {
  font-family: "myFont";

  order: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div>
        <label>
            {% trans 'constraint_number' %}:
    
        </label>

        <span>
            {{ correspondence.number }}
        </span>

</div>
```